# Weird zooming effect with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiscrollview

I've got a basic UIScrollView displaying an image.

Zooming in works fine but when I try zoom out the whole UIScrollView kind've shrinks into the top left corner of the screen. I've tried playing around with the `minimumZoomScale` but that's not really doing anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Zac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What view are you returning in your viewForZoomingInScrollView delegate method? It sounds like you might be returning a pointer to the UIScrollView itself. Typically, you'll want to create a subview to hold your content instead.

Comment: Ah, apparently I was returning something completely different. Thanks, helped me spot a silly problem!